# IMAP: Export addresses of all receivers

Tags: export, imap

I'm trying to get a way to export all the addresses in Sent email folders of some IMAP accounts.

The goal is to export the emails to CSV, TXT, whatever... I just need them stored somewhere else.

Is there any programs/scripts for this? 
(Linux user here btw, Windows solutions are also accepted).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[IMAP Addresses Exporter](http://www.raneri.it/imap-addresses-exporter) for Mac and Windows takes a label from your mailbox and exports a list of all the senders, removing the duplicates.

***Disclaimer: I'm involved into the project.***

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Great app, kinda overpriced. I guess 5$ would be the recommended price.

Comment: @TCB13 thank you so much. I'm not the only who decide about the price, anyway I will report your suggestion :)